# Import CSV file in MySql using PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I've to import a CSV file in a table of a MySql database using PHP code. The CSV file is the following:

"2016-09-02", "100.01", "4005.09", "5000", "1.09", "120.09", "100.5", "200.77"
"2016-09-03", "150.01", "4205.09", "5600", "1.10", "150.09", "300.5", "300.77"

File permissions are 755.

Table fields are 9 (id field included): the firts is a datetime field and other are float fields.
The code I use is the following and it will run on the server site:

```
$csvFile = "../scripts/tabella.csv";

$db = @mysql_connect('**.***.**.***', 'Sql******', '*******');
@mysql_select_db('Sql******_*');

$query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \' '. $csvFile .' \' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' ';

if(!mysql_query($query)){
    die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($db);
```

First error is returned from mysql_error: 'file not found'. The CSV file is in 'www.mysite.it/mysite/scripts/tabella.CSV'. Its permissions are 755. I tried to use realpath($csvFile) function but the error is always the same.

I tried to run the same query in localhost and there isn't this error but only a record is inserted into the table and its fild values are NULL.

Can you help me, please?
Thanks!

Comment: can you check if you have `FILE` privilege? you need this privilege to execute `LOAD DATA`

Comment: CSV file permissions are 755

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_error to get the error

```
 if(!mysql_query($query)){
      die(mysql_error());

 }
```

Comment: Thanks.. Error is 'file not found'. It is into www.mysite.it/mysite/scripts/tabella.csv. Its permissions are 755. Which is the correct path for the query?

Comment: Try using Absolute path to the file

Comment: how to recover the absolute path to the file? I already used realpath PHP function but the error is the same 'File not found'..

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
$csvFile = "../scripts/tabella.csv";

//The Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);

//Check for successful connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) echo "Error - Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error; die;

$query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \' '. $csvFile .' \' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' ';
//Do your query
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

//Close the connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this simple way to import your CSV data to Mysql database.The `file` is a HTML element name to `browse` your file path.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {
        $name= $filesop[0];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tab(name) VALUES ('$name')");
        $c = $c + 1;
    }

    if($sql){
        echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ." recoreds";
    }else{
        echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This coding It's work

```
<?php 
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if($_FILES['file']['name'])
    {
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        if($filename[1] == 'csv')
        {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while($data = fgetcsv($handle))
            {
                $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);  
                $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);
                $query = "INSERT into excel(excel_name, excel_phone) values('$item1','$item2')";
                mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            echo "<script>alert('Import done');</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div align="center">
            <label>Select CSV File:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Import" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: explain me in deep plz